# Why can't I put string into stringstream object?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I need to make a C++ program to enlist every word in sentence without repetition.
I tried putting every word int stringstream object, but it doesn't put it at all??
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool is_there_any(string word, stringstream& words)
{
    string w;
    while (words >> w)
    {
        if (!word.compare(w))
            return true;
    }
    words << word;//This one doesn't work for some reason...
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    string sentence, word;
    getline(cin, sentence);
    stringstream stream, words;
    stream.str(sentence);
    words.clear();
    while (stream >> word)
    {
        if (!is_there_any(word, words))
            cout << word << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried debugging and showed me that this line of code `words << word;` doesn't work. It doesn't insert anything in "words", and word isn't empty string.

Comment: Isn't it going to be confusing to use `words` as both an input and output stream?

Comment: In C++ you cannot switch a stream between reading and writing without performing a positioning operation in between, something you are failing to do. Suggest you give up on using a `stringstream` for storage and use something like a `vector<string>` instead, much easier,

Comment: *I need to make a C++ program to enlist every word in sentence without repetition* -- Use a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`.  It doesn't look like your code will accomplish this goal.

Comment: Plus you are writing your words to the stream without any spaces in between, so even if you got the writing to work you wouldn't be able to read back the individual words.

Comment: Uglyness to append to the stringstreams inner string: `words.str(words.str() + word); `

Answer (score 1):

The approach is fundamentally flawed. You're attempting to do a O(N^2) operation whereby for every word in the sentence you re-process the sentence and try to stuff the word back into it after.

This is neither intuitive nor performant, and it requires some ugly hackery to make it even work at all.

A better approach is to maintain a set of words that you've encountered so far. Then you simply read words and try to add them to the set. You only output those words which were not already in the set. Not only is this code more efficient, but it's easier to follow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_set<string> words;
    string sentence, word;

    while (getline(cin, sentence))
    {
        istringstream iss(sentence);
        while(iss >> word)
        {
            if (words.insert(word).second)
            {
                cout << word << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
This is a sentence
This is another sentence
```

Output:

```
This
is
a
sentence
another
```

Answer (score 0):

As you read on a previous answer done by [paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553090/paddy), your approach is not the best one; `set` class is always the answer when you are trying to get unrepeated objects, in this case you wanted unrepeated words.

Although your approach is wrong, i'm going to point some silly mistakes that maybe for others project will help you and won't have to be bothered by the ghost of "what did I do wrong in this function":

- On `is_there_any()` function you're emptying the sstringstream by using the `>>` operator. That is why you do not get the unrepeated words inside that stream, instead, you're always checking an empty stream.

A way to solve this is issue is by doing an actual copy of the previous content on another sstringstream object and using it:

**NOTE THAT THIS IS NOT THE BEST APPROACH AS YOU'RE ITERATING OVER EVERY UNREPEATED WORD FOR EACH PENDING WORD TO BE CHECKED (cost of O(n^2))**

```
bool is_there_any(string& word, stringstream& words)
{
  string w;
  stringstream copyOfWords;
  copyOfWords.str(words.str());
  while (copyOfWords >> w)
  {
      if (!word.compare(w))
          return true;
  }
  words <<word <<" ";
  return false;
}
```

- You should not use the `clear()` function from sstringstream unless you produced some exception and you're currently treatening it because you still need to use that object.

It does not affect your desired output but it's something that might confuse you on the future (I think you wanted to clear the stream buffer from sstringstream but it doesn't do that at all, it's used to clear error state flags).